# How do I print the output of an iterative function in one column and print the output of a second iterative function in a second, adjacent column?

Tags: python-3.x, string.format

I am working on a script to calculate the number and addresses of subnets given a main network address. I have 2 functions (for now) - AvailableNetworks(), and BroadcastAddy(). I want to print these functions in 2 columns, so each row contains a network id, and the broadcast address of that subnet.
To do this: The first column needs to contain the output of AvailableNetworks(). The second column needs to have the output of BroadcastAddy().

My end goal to use .format() with "{:^30}{:^30}{:^30}". However, .format() seems to have significant problems iterating through lists of lists, or at least I have major issues telling it how to do so.

Here are the 2 functions I've written:

```
MainNetwork = input("What is the main network id address?")
SubnetsDesired = input("How many subnets do you want to create?")

GoodNets = []
BroadcastAddresses = []

def AvailableNetworks():
    NetArray = [2, 4, 8, 16, 32, 64, 128, 256]
    HostArray = [256, 128, 64, 32, 16, 8, 4, 2]
    for i in NetArray:
        if i >= int(SubnetsDesired):
            NumbSubnets = i
            SubnetIndex = NetArray.index(i)
            NumIps=HostArray[SubnetIndex + 1]
            print("Available Networks:")
            ipaddy = MainNetwork.split(".")
            ipaddy = list(map(int, ipaddy))
            for i in range(NumbSubnets-1):
                ipaddy[-1] += NumIps
                GoodNets.append('.'.join(str(i) for i in ipaddy))
            break

def BroadcastAddy():
    NetArray = [2, 4, 8, 16, 32, 64, 128, 256]
    HostArray = [256, 128, 64, 32, 16, 8, 4, 2]
    for i in NetArray:
        if i >= int(SubnetsDesired):
            NumbSubnets = i
            SubnetIndex = NetArray.index(i)
            NumIps = HostArray[SubnetIndex + 1]
            print("Broadcast Adress:")
            ipaddy = MainNetwork.split(".")
            ipaddy = list(map(int, ipaddy))
            for i in range(NumbSubnets - 1):
                ipaddy[-1] += NumIps -1
                BroadcastAddresses.append('.'.join(str(i) for i in ipaddy))
                ipaddy[-1] += 1
            break
```

I used zip() to combine elements of Goodnets with elements of Broadcast Addresses that had equivalent index number.

```
if __name__== '__main__':
    AvailableNetworks()
    BroadcastAddy()

    # This combines lists so 
    FinalReport = zip(GoodNets, BroadcastAddresses)
    # zip() creates immutable tuples that will give you hell if you try to run them through .format()
    # So I convert FinalReport back into list of lists
    FinalReport = [list(elem) for elem in FinalReport]
    # Bug check (Delete this before final)
    print("this is the type of final report:", type(FinalReport))
    # Bug check, print the FinalReport to see what inside. 
    print(FinalReport)
    # Formatted, when combined with .format() will create 2 columns. I've printed to column titles
    # to prove this works. 
    formatted = "{:^30}{:^30}"
    print(formatted.format("Network Addresses", "Broadcast Addresses"))
    # Now, I try to print FinalReport in 2 columns. 
    for list in FinalReport:
        for num in list:
            print(formatted.format(num, num))
            break
```

As mentioned, I've reviewed the literature as best as I could and I have not found any documentation that teaches how to print the output of one function in one column and a second function in an immediately adjacent column. I could be wrong though. Would appreciate any help this wonderful community could provide. Thank you.

Answer (score 0):

I think what you're trying to do would be remedied with the following:

`for list in FinalReport:
    print(formatted.format(list[0], list[1]))`

Each iteration you had before would be in the form:

`['192.168.1.32', '192.168.1.31']`

With your inner `for` loop though you were iterating over the first element in the list `192.168.1.32` and then calling `break` so never getting to the second element.

The code snippet provided would just iterate over the list of lists and accessing each pair by it's relative index.